# Pass onece-off information from component to ancestor component in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state

I have a structure of components like this:

```
<Ancestor>
  ...
    ...
      ...
         <Child thing="foo"/>
         <Child thing="bar"/>
         ...
      ...
         <Child thing="foo" />
```

It would be really useful if Ancestor knew the value of all the value of the "thing" values of all the ultimate Child components. These values never change in the lifetime of each component.

I know this is achievable using useContext, or passing a callback all the way down. But in this simplified case where these props don't change, I wonder if there is a simpler solution.

Answer (score 1):

A solution is to use the legacy React API [`Children.forEach(children, fn, thisArg?)`](https://react.dev/reference/react/Children#children-foreach)

Recursively find the `thing` prop of all `Child` components in the `Ancestor` component tree.

```
import './styles.css';
import React, { useMemo } from 'react';

const getChildThing = (children) => {
    const things = [];
    const work = (arr) => {
        React.Children.forEach(arr, (c) => {
            if (c.type === Child) {
                things.push(c.props.thing);
            } else if (c.props.children) {
                return work(c.props.children);
            }
        });
    };
    work(children);
    return things;
};

const Child = ({ thing }) => <div>{thing}</div>;
const Ancestor = ({ children }) => {
    const things = useMemo(() => getChildThing(children), [children]);
    console.log(things);
    return <div>{children}</div>;
};

export default function App() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Ancestor>
                <Child thing="a" />
                <Child thing="b" />
                <div>
                    <Child thing="c" />
                    <div>
                        <Child thing="d" />
                        <div>
                            <Child thing="e" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </Ancestor>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Logs:

```
["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-76800119-nk9t8v?file=/src/App.js)